# Flutter Video screen not closing on completion when WillPopScope implemented

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I recently implemented WillPopScope on the VideoPlayer package in my app:

```
child: WillPopScope(
                  onWillPop: () async => false,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                ),
```

I use this to stop the swipe back, that was occurring before. Which works fine.

However it has resulted in another error. When the VideoPlayer completes it should close the screen and this is no longer happening. It worked fine before.

Here is my exit screen code:

```
void closeScreen() async {
  final _exercises = Provider.of<Exercises>(context, listen: false);
  _exercises.increasePlayCount(widget.exercise.id);
  print('VIDEO FINISHED ... CLOSE!!');
  widget.exercise.setRecentPlayed(widget.exercise);
  Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
}
```

This method is being called fine as the print statement is being executed as expected.

I hav tried changing the placement of the WillPopScope but that hasn't fixed the problem. Could someone please let me know how I can correct this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest making sure that your widget is a `StatefulWidget`, and doing something like this:

Add a boolean to state indicating if the video has finished:

```
bool isFinished = false;
```

Alter your `WillPopScope` like this:

```
WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => isFinished,
  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
)
```

Finally, update your `closeVideo` to toggle the value of `isFinished`

```
void closeScreen() async {
  final _exercises = Provider.of<Exercises>(context, listen: false);
  _exercises.increasePlayCount(widget.exercise.id);
  isFinished = true;
  print('VIDEO FINISHED ... CLOSE!!');
  widget.exercise.setRecentPlayed(widget.exercise);
  Navigator.of(context).maybePop();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
    overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
}
```

Comment: Yes this does fix the original error as described. However now it goes back two screens instead of one. It didn't do that before the WillPopScope implementation. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: Can you post the code that is calling the `closeScreen` method?

Comment: It's a listener within the initState method:
_controller.addListener(() {
      if (startedPlaying &&
          !_controller.value.isPlaying &&
          _controller.value.position == _controller.value.duration) {
        closeScreen();
      }
    });

Comment: I see, since controller listeners run every time the object changes, is it possible that `closeScreen` is actually being ran more than once (check the console for logs), even though you're just expecting it to run a single time? Also, is the controller being disposed of properly on the `StatefulWidget`? I think either of those _could_ trigger that listener to run more than once.